# TypeError: Model 'purchase.order' does not exist in registry

Tags: odoo

I have this error in Odoo 11:

```
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 146, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 250, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 428, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name)
TypeError: Model 'purchase.order' does not exist in registry.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Community. Please refer the method of asking question in stack overflow.

Comment: In particular, have a look at how to create a [mcve].

Comment: When do you get this error? Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 6):

Try to add 'purchase' to 'depends' in your manifest file.

Comment: 'depends: '['base',
                'purchase',],

Answer (score 0):

Install the purchase model in the apps menu, or upgrade it if it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the sequence of the init.py file import class. Make sure you inherit the model, that will be above or prior to the import in the init.py file.